# Custom Record Home Template with Pinned Sidebar and Header

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-page

I would like to create a custom **Record Home Template** in Lightning, similar to the standard `Grouped Header and One Region` Record Home Template, where:

- the header and the left sidebar would be pinned
- they would persist whenever the user browse to related related lists

(here's how the `Grouped Header and One Region` look like)

[image]

I could not find anything in the documentation allowing this behavior to be done with a custom `<aura:component implements="lightning:recordHomeTemplate">`.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Can you also add a screenshot of what are you looking help for?

Comment: @sanketkumar Added in original post.